# Unable to create netlink socket: Protocol not supported

Tags: linux, sockets, ipv6, netlink

I found an example about intercepting IPv6 packets using netfilter along with libipq library.

It begins by declaring and creating an ipq_handle structure:

```
struct ipq_handle *h;
h = ipq_create_handle(0, NFPROTO_IPV6);
if (!h) die(h);
```

The corresponding die() function is like the following

```
static void die(struct ipq_handle *h)
ipq_error("Passer");
ipq_destroy_handle(h);
exit(1);
```

However, the program fails to run properly generating the following:

> Passer: Unable to create netlink socket: Protocol not supported

Anyone knows the likely cause of the problem?

Comment: Do you have IPv6 enabled in the operating system?

Comment: Obvious answer: IPv6 is not supported in that version?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 12.04 on my virtual machines. I guess IPv6  is enabled by default. Actually I configured global IPv6 addresses and managed to send IPv6 UDP sockets before attempting to use netlink sockets!

Comment: I think you need the ip6_queue kernel module. Its not part of my ubuntu 13.04 default desktop install at least. Edit: maybe I am a bit out of date: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9/Documentation/ABI/removed/ip_queue (I hope the libipq devs are not)

Comment: @thuovila Apparently it was deprecated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with ip(6)_queue, libipq has been deprecated. Quoting from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libipq):

> Libipq has been deprecated in favour of the newer [libnetfilter_queue](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html) in Linux kernel-2.6.14 onwards.